# Post request must return Http code + body or Http code + URI?

Tags: java, spring, rest, post, rules

i have an API with two versions of an POST handler

first version:

```
@PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Note> insertNote(@RequestBody Note nota){
        noteRepository.save(nota);
        return new ResponseEntity<Note>(nota, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

this version return an entity with a 201 code and a body

Second version:

```
@PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity createNote(@RequestBody Note nota, UriComponentsBuilder ucb){
        Note savedNote = noteRepository.save(nota);
        URI locationOfNewNote = ucb
                .path("api/v1/notes/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(savedNote.getId())
                .toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(locationOfNewNote).build();
    }
```

this version return a 201 code with the followed header:
`location= http://localhost:8080/api/v1/notes/12`

Which of these versions should I use? Which of these is best in terms of good practices and web rules?

Comment: If I'm consuming an API and creating a resource, I'd generally always want the created entity back in the response body. Whether you want to return its location is a design decision. If you do want to return a location header, I'd highly recommend automating the generation of the location. I don't see a ton of value in the location, unless the fetch URL is in an odd place. Usually an api is `POST /entity` and `GET /entity/{id}`, so if you're following that pattern, the fetch URL should be obvious.